# Combinations - Ways to pick from 6 people to go to 3 locations

Tags: permutations, combinations

I've stumbled upon the question of:

Six diplomats are awaiting assignments to foreign embassies. If 1 of these is to be assigned to Germany, 2 to France and 3 to England, in how many ways can the arrangement be made?

I thought that it could be:
p(6,1)+p(5,2)+p(3,3)
However That seems quite off now that I look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over this question.

So we have six  people.

We pick any one of these in six ways, to go to Germany.

Then, we pick any two of them, to go to France. This is done in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.

The remaining three will all go to England, so there is no choice there.

Hence, all we have to do is to find the number of ways of sending one person to Germany and two to France. This is $6 \times \binom{5}{2} = 60$ ways.

A better answer is that this is just $\binom{6}{3,2,1}$, the multinomial expression, which evaluates to $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60$.

Comment: So you used a combination instead of a permutation because there is no explicit order to choose the 1 from 6, 2 from 5, etc?

Comment: Exactly, @SamCampbell

Comment: @SamCampbell  The other mistake you made is that you added when you should have multiplied.  For each of the six ways a diplomat can be assigned to go to Germany, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways of assigning two diplomats to go to France.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2}$ to assign the diplomats to Germany and France by the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  We use the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) when two events cannot occur at the same time, which is not the case here.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the clarification.